# Pivot table with multiple Values by Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I was wondering if the solution to the ticket at the following link was ever found
[Pivot on multiple fields and export from Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352120/pivot-on-multiple-fields-and-export-from-access/43850411#43850411).

I am trying to get results from an access table in the following format where: *V1* (value 1) is a number and *V2* (value 2) is timestamp (`hh:mm:ss`).

Basically the report pulls for current month so eventually there would be a day at the top for every day of the month and a corresponding Number and time value for each day.

```
               April 1          April 2          April 3
Manager      V1   V2         V1      V2         V1      V2
John Doe     4   5:43:12      1    0:56:32      2    3:15:12
```

It is an elapsed time. I have been looking at Allen Browne's post and I am most of the way there I think. I created two tables: 1) for *V1* which is a *number of dials*; and 2) for *V2* which is *total talk time*. I then used Allen Browne's method but I cannot get the format of the time to be in `hh:mm:ss`. It is that way in the base table but whatever I try it always seems to just show 1 digit.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(IIf([FldName]="DIALS",Val([DIALS].[DIALS]),
              Val(Format([T‌​ALKTIME].[TT],"hh:nn‌​:ss")))) AS TheValue 
SELECT TALKTIME.Manager, DIALS.TW_Program_Code, 
       [DIALS]![VSE_FirstName] & " " & [DIALS]![VSE_Surname_Name] AS REP 
FROM tblXtabColumns, TALKTIME 
INNER JOIN DIALS 
ON (TALKTIME.TW_Program_Code = DIALS.TW_Program_Code) 
AND (TALKTIME.VSE_FirstName = DIALS.VSE_FirstName) 
AND (TALKTIME.VSE_Surname_Name = DIALS.VSE_Surname_Name) 
AND (TALKTIME.Period = DIALS.Period) AND (TALKTIME.[Manager] = DIALS.[Manager])
WHERE (((Month([TALKTIME].[Period])) = Month(Now())-1)) 
GROUP BY TALKTIME.Manager, DIALS.TW_Program_Code, 
         [DIALS]![VSE_FirstName] & " " & [DIALS]![VSE_Surname_Name] 
PIVOT [DIALS].[Period] & " " & [FldName];
```

Comment: Why are you using Val() function on the elapsed time? Purpose of Val() function is to return a number (integer or short, no punctuation and no alpha).

Comment: I have just been googling and trying things. I am lost to be honest. And if I don't put anything I get a data Type Mismatch error

Comment: Can't SUM a text value. If the elapsed time is saved as seconds then you should sum the seconds without formatting to h:n:s. Do formatting after all the arithmetic calcs are done. Don't Format within that Iif().

Comment: Really, best place to do formatting is in textbox on form or report. However, building a stable report based on CROSSTAB is not easy.

Comment: is it possible to format the elapsed time columns of each output excel file once they have been created using vba from access? Something like - in folder Temp - format any column in any workbook that contains TT in the column header   probably reaching at this point :)

Comment: You want to export to Excel? Possibly, but not finding intrinsic function in Excel so would likely be a more complex custom function. Topic for another question. Or don't export the CROSSTAB directly. Build another query using the CROSSTAB and apply formatting in that 'final' manipulation for export.

Answer (score 0):

Is that time of day or elapsed time?

Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues. Cannot have multi-line headers. The date would have to be concatenated with the field that provides the V1 and V2 header. Is there even a field that can be used to provide the "V1" and "V2" headers? If not, calculate it. One way:

`SELECT *, DCount("*","Table1","Manager='" & [Manager] & "' AND ID <" & [ID])+1 AS Seq FROM Table1 WHERE Month([datefield]) = 4 AND Year([datefield])=2017;`

Now use that query in CROSSTAB. Either build 2 CROSSTAB queries and join them or use Allen Browne approach. Example CROSSTAB to pivot only the "V1" data.

`TRANSFORM First(Query1.Reading) AS DailyReading
SELECT Query1.Manager
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Manager
PIVOT Format([ReadDate],"mmm d") & " : " & [Seq] & "Reading";`

Comment: It is an elapsed time. I have been looking at Allen Browne's post and I am most of the way there I think.
 I created 2 tables ( 1 for V1 which is a number of dials) and a second  for V2 (which is total talk time)

I then used Allen Browne's method but I cannot get the format of the time to be in hh:mm:ss. It is that way in the base table but whatever I try it always seems to just show 1 digit.

Comment: Is the elapsed time in a date/time field? Possibly use Format() to stabilize. Format([fieldname],"hh:mm:ss"). Should probably edit your original post to show the SQL there then delete the two comments.

Comment: It gets created as a short text field

this is what formats the field from seconds to hh:mm:ss and it ends up in a table as short text

TT: Format(Sum([CUST_TT])*Val("0.000694444444")/60,"hh:nn:ss")

Comment: If I remove the TT: Format(Sum([CUST_TT])*Val("0.000694444444")/60,"hh:nn:ss")  from the initial make table query and leave it as seconds (what the data comes in as) the query returns what I want it to except it shows the elapsed time as seconds and not in the hh:mm:ss format. Can the step to return the data in the Transform step also format it?

`TRANSFORM Sum(IIf([FldName]="DIALS",CDbl([DIALS].[DIALS]),CDbl(([TALKTIME].[CUST_TT])))) AS TheValue`

Comment: I think not with Allen's all-in-one query approach.

Comment: thank you for your time and patience. I appreciate it