# Ms Access 2016 how to display 10 images horizontially in continuous mode using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a way to display 10 images horizontally and in continuous mode on an MS Access form using VBA.

At the moment I'm using a cross tab query  As the query is slow and the temp table needs to be regenerated every time a different sort is needed, I was looking for a VBA solution.

I also need it to be able to select an individual image and get a popup form for more info (like in the cross tab pic), etc. and be able to sort the form according to various selections.

So far after a long search the only solution I've found is on another forum which I can post if needed but haven't been able to get the code to work fully.

This is a pic of the working cross tab form...

[image]

This is the current not working one...

[image]

I managed to get 10 images across but they just repeat each row.

The code I have so far is...

```
Private Sub genrpt()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim X As Integer

    X = 0
    Do
        Me("Img" & X + 1).Picture = Me.lst0.Column(1, I)
        I = I + 1
        X = X + 1
    Loop Until X >= 10
End Sub
```

So if anybody can help I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: I would like to see this link that you mentioned.  Also, is the `ME` in your code referring to a subform instance where the subform is in continuous display?

Comment: @toonice Thank u for the edit Btw. The me.Img refers to a Imagebox 1 of 10 and Me.Lst0 refers to the list box shown in the picture 2  Here is the link u requested  [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28354225/Access-Display-Vertical-Data-Horizontally.html)

Comment: If the user adjusts the size of the window will you wish to make the row size more or less than `10` as appropriate or is the row size fixed at `10`?

Comment: At the moment I use 10 image boxes to fill the form so hadn't thought that far ahead to honest, be a nice feature to add tho especially for different screen resolutions

Comment: I have a solution that solves the problem of the repeated row.  I just have to make a few changes and I should be able to get the movie details to come up when a movie is selected.  After that I will type up a explanation of my Answer (lots of typing there - it could take a while).  Once the explanation is posted I will consider the Answer to have been completed and awaiting a decision on acceptance and upvoting / rejection with details of more work needed.  Once we are satisfied that this much has been achieved, I shall try to make the row size more dynamic.  No guarantees, but I am curious.

Comment: Thanks toonice for all ur effort, I found some free code on a site that changes ur database to suit the screen resolution of the user called FORM RESIZER by Jamies Software that will come in handy. [link](http://www.jamiessoftware.tk)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I will look into that once I have caught up on a few of my continuing questions.

Answer (score 1):

My solution dispenses with the one you have been attempting.  It would have established a row of pictures *only* - they would have been jammed together and I'm not sure if you would have been able to refer to each individually, configure them as controls or links, or display a short piece of text below each.  If there *is* way around these problems, then I would actually like to know more about it.

Instead, my solution is based around a table of the following structure...

```
+----------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fldID          | AutoNumber | An automatically generated  number used to uniquely identify a `movie`.      |
| fldDescription | Short Text | A short description of the `movie`, typically just the `name` of the `movie` |
| fldPicture     | Short Text | The full path to the `picture` file                                          |
| fldSynopsis    | Long Text  | A lot of text about the `movie` - for testing the details form               |
+----------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It is not clear from your Question if you are storing a reference to the location of the `pictures` or a copy of the image itself in your database.  I have chosen to go with the former option here.

I use three forms in this solution.  The first is `frmMain`, which is host to a title and a subform control called `subFrmSub` that is linked to the form `frmSub`.

The second form, `frmSub`, has its `Default Views` property set to `Continuous Forms`.  Its `Record Source` is the following query, which I have called `qryPicturesPivoted`...

```
TRANSFORM MAX( prePivot.columnValue ) AS MaxOfcolumnValue
SELECT prePivot.groupNumber AS recNumber
FROM ( SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1 AS groupNumber,
              "ID" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1) MOD 10 + 1, "00" ) AS columnNumber,
              fldID AS columnValue
       FROM qryRecordNumberFinder
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1,
              "Description" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1) MOD 10 + 1, "00" ),
              fldDescription AS columnValue
       FROM qryRecordNumberFinder
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1,
              "Picture" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1) MOD 10 + 1, "00" ),
              fldPicture
       FROM qryRecordNumberFinder
     ) AS prePivot
GROUP BY prePivot.groupNumber
PIVOT prePivot.columnNumber;
```

This query is itself based around the query `qryRecordNumberFinder`, which follows...

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber,
       leftTable.fldID AS fldID,
       leftTable.fldDescription AS fldDescription,
       leftTable.fldPicture AS fldPicture
FROM tblPictures AS leftTable
INNER JOIN tblPictures AS rightTable ON leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID
GROUP BY leftTable.fldID,
         leftTable.fldDescription,
         leftTable.fldPicture;
```

`qryRecordNumberFinder` selects the fields from each record in one instance of `tblPictures` (which I have given the alias of `leftTable` to) that are relevant to `frmSub` and appends to each a copy of each record from another instance of `tblPictures` (`rightTable`) that has an `fldID` value less than or equal to that of the record from `leftTable`.  It then groups the records by the values from `leftTable` and returns a count of records in each group, effectively appending a record number to each record from `tblPictures`.

`qryRecordNumberFinder` is based on [JokoSumanto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1871675/jokosumanto)'s Answer to the Question at [How to show row number in Access query like ROW_NUMBER in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683226/how-to-show-row-number-in-access-query-like-row-number-in-sql).

Sadly, there is no row number facility such as SQL-Server's `ROW_NUMBER()` in Access.

Since there appears to be no ready way in Access to pivot more than two fields with just one of the fields becoming the new field names, `qryPicturesPivoted` starts of with a subquery that recreates the results of `qryRecordNumberFinder` in three fields.

The first is `groupNumber`.  It is will become the pivoted data's record number.  It is calculated by first subtracting `1` from `RecordNumber`, turning `1` through `10` into `0` through `9`, `11` through `20` into `10` through `19`, etc.  This operation is necessary so that the `\` operator (also known as the `DIV` operator and not to be confused with the *division* operator `/`) will return the same number for each `RecordNumber` in a group of `10` records.  `1` is then added to the number produced by the `\` operation so that the first value of `groupNumber` is `1` and not `0`.

A similar operation that uses the `MOD` operator instead of the `\` operator is used to generate the `columnNumber` field, which will become the pivoted data's field names.

`columnValue` will contain the data from `tblPictures` selected by `qryRecordNumberFinder`.

`qryPicturesPivoted` is based on [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson)'s Answer to the Question at [Pivot on multiple fields and export from Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352120/pivot-on-multiple-fields-and-export-from-access).

Each instance of `frmSub` places the values for its record from `qryPicturesPivoted` into one of `30` controls, which are comprised of `10` groups of `3` controls - one for a `movie`'s image, one for the `movie`'s description / name (which has its `Tab Stop` property set to `No`) and one for the `movie`'s `fldID` value (which has its `Visible` property set to `No`).  The record number is placed in another (invisible to the user) control for reference purposes.

Each group of `3` controls has placed over it a command button that has no `Caption` and has its `Back Style` and its `Border Style` set to `Transparent`, effectively making the button invisible but still available to the user.  This is done so that the user may click anywhere on the image or text field *or* the black-space contained within the button's bounds to summon the details form.  Each command button uses a variation on the following code to open the details form to the selected record...

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDetails", , , "fldID = " & Me.txtID01, acFormReadOnly
```

The third form I mentioned is `frmDetails`.  It is based on `tblPictures` and contains the image, the description / name, and the synopsis.

When the form `frmMain` is loaded I use the following code to set the height of the subform control, the detail section and the form so as to ensure that all the rows of pictures are displayed in `frmMain` without need for a scroll-bar *within* the subform control...

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim recordCount As Integer
    Dim subFrmSubHeight As Integer


    recordCount = DCount("fldID", "tblPictures")
    subFrmSubHeight = (((recordCount - 1) \ 10) + 1) * 6

    Me.InsideHeight = (2 + subFrmSubHeight + 1) * 567
    Me.Detail.Height = (2 + subFrmSubHeight + 1) * 567
    Me.subFrmSub.Height = subFrmSubHeight * 567
End Sub
```

When using VBA to set a height you can not specify the unit of measurement (such as with `3cm`) and are instead forced to use TWIPS.  Please see [accessbob-pdx](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/accessbob-pdx/?ws=usercard-mini)'s Answer to the Question at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f64af695-21f7-421f-9c7c-b398e15ab085/unit-of-measure-in-access?forum=accessdev.

There is no need for a list-box in my solution.

I have not yet been able to reliably highlight a specific `movie` by setting that `movie`'s command button's `Border Style` to `Solid`.  Every method I've tried either sets no button's `Border Style` to `Solid`, or it sets the `Border Style` to `Solid` for every instance of that control, effectively highlighting the entire column.  I have a Question posted on this matter, but for now I'm not going to spend any more time on that problem.

I will post a link to a copy of the database as soon as I find a suitable hosting service.

I hope that this solution will be fast enough for you.  If not, there are a number of refinements that can be made to your database to make it more efficient, but it is difficult to comment on what they are without knowing a number more details about your database.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

**Appendix 1**

To allow for refining of the output to just those movies starting with a chosen letter I have defined the following function in VBA...

```
Private Function GetRefineToLetterString(parameterLetter As String) As String
    GetRefineToLetterString = "TRANSFORM Max(prePivot.columnValue) AS MaxOfcolumnValue " & _
                              "SELECT prePivot.groupNumber AS recNumber " & _
                              "FROM ( SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1 AS groupNumber, 'ID' & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 10 + 1, '00' ) AS columnNumber, fldID As columnValue FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber, leftTable.fldID AS fldID FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS leftTable INNER JOIN ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures  WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS rightTable ON leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID GROUP BY leftTable.fldID ) AS qryRecordNumberFinderID " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description' & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 10 + 1, '00' ), fldDescription FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber, leftTable.fldID AS fldID, fldDescription FROM ( SELECT fldID, fldDescription FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS leftTable INNER JOIN ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS rightTable ON leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID GROUP BY leftTable.fldID, leftTable.fldDescription ) AS qryRecordNumberFinderDescription " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 10 + 1, 'Picture' & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 10 + 1, '00' ), fldPicture FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber, leftTable.fldID AS fldID, fldPicture FROM ( SELECT fldID, fldPicture FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS leftTable INNER JOIN ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS rightTable ON leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID GROUP BY leftTable.fldID, leftTable.fldPicture ) AS qryRecordNumberFinderPicture " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description02', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 = 1 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description03', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 2 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description04', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description05', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 4 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description06', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description07', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 6 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description08', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 7 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description09', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 8 " & _
                              "       UNION ALL SELECT COUNT( * ) \ 10 + 1, 'Description10', NULL FROM ( SELECT fldID FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) AS matchingCount02 HAVING ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tblPictures WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "' ) MOD 10 BETWEEN 1 AND 9 " & _
                              "     )  AS prePivot " & _
                              "GROUP BY prePivot.groupNumber " & _
                              "PIVOT prePivot.columnNumber;"
End Function
```

Then for each letter's command button I added the following code to the `On Click` event, with that button's letter inseide the brackets...

```
Me!subFrmSub.Form.RecordSource = GetRefineToLetterString("A")
```

The first reason why I have gone with this rather large and ugly function is that Access does not like using parametrised queries (or queries that are ultimately based on a parametrised query) as the basis for a `PIVOT`.  As such the search criteria need to be coded into the statement rather than passed through as a parameter.  The statement used here is based on the queries mentioned earlier, `qryPicturesPivoted` and `qryRecordNumberFinder`, with the code for the two queries having been merged into one statement.  Further, since we want to display a refined dataset rather than all the records, I have replaced all references to `tblPictures` with variations on the following code...

```
SELECT fldID,
       fldDescription,
       fldPicture
FROM tblPictures
WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = '" & parameterLetter & "'
```

Once the parameter letter has been incorporated, the string become something like...

```
SELECT fldID,
       fldDescription,
       fldPicture
FROM tblPictures
WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = 'A'
```

The statement proceeds from there largely as before, with two modifications.  Firstly, I have removed unnecessary field selections.  Secondly, I have added `UNION`'s that will buffer out our results to ensure that each field in the instance of `frmSub` corresponding to the last row will always be connected to a value (`NULL` or otherwise).  Without the buffer data it we get a `#NAME?` message for each unoccupied `Description` field.

I have also added a button that enables you to search for `movies` that start with a digit.

Quite frankly I feel that many of the problems encountered thus far can be easily avoided or corrected for if we implement a solution that displays the records on the main form in pages of, say, `50` entries and dispenses with the subform altogether.  I shall proceed to develop such a solution.

**Appendix 2**

One alternative approach to this problem is to dispense with the subform approach and break the record-set up into pages of `40` records to be displayed on the main form.  I did try for pages of `50`, but Access complained that the `PIVOT` query produced too many fields (there is a limit of 255 fields in Access).

The query used to populate the form when it is opened follows...

```
TRANSFORM MAX(columnValue) AS MaxOfcolumnValue
SELECT groupNumber AS recNumber
FROM ( SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 40 + 1 AS groupNumber,
              "ID" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 40 + 1, "00" ) AS columnNumber,
              fldID AS columnValue
       FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber,
                     leftTable.fldID,
                     leftTable.fldDescription
              FROM tblPictures AS leftTable
              INNER JOIN tblPictures AS rightTable ON ( leftTable.fldDescription > rightTable.fldDescription OR
                                                        ( leftTable.fldDescription = rightTable.fldDescription AND
                                                          leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID ) )
              GROUP BY leftTable.fldID,
                       leftTable.fldDescription
              ORDER BY leftTable.fldDescription
            ) AS subqueryID
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 40 + 1,
              "Description" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 40 + 1, "00" ),
              fldDescription
       FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber,
                     leftTable.fldDescription
              FROM tblPictures AS leftTable
              INNER JOIN tblPictures AS rightTable ON ( leftTable.fldDescription > rightTable.fldDescription OR
                                                        ( leftTable.fldDescription = rightTable.fldDescription AND
                                                          leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID ) )
              GROUP BY leftTable.fldID,
                       leftTable.fldDescription
              ORDER BY leftTable.fldDescription
            ) AS subqueryDescription
       UNION ALL
       SELECT ( RecordNumber - 1 ) \ 40 + 1,
              "Picture" & FORMAT( ( RecordNumber - 1 ) MOD 40 + 1, "00" ),
              fldPicture
       FROM ( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS RecordNumber,
                     leftTable.fldID,
                     leftTable.fldDescription,
                     leftTable.fldPicture
              FROM tblPictures AS leftTable
              INNER JOIN tblPictures AS rightTable ON ( leftTable.fldDescription > rightTable.fldDescription OR
                                                        ( leftTable.fldDescription = rightTable.fldDescription AND
                                                          leftTable.fldID >= rightTable.fldID ) )
              GROUP BY leftTable.fldID,
                       leftTable.fldDescription,
                       leftTable.fldPicture
              ORDER BY leftTable.fldDescription
            ) AS subqueryPicture
     )  AS prePivot
GROUP BY groupNumber
PIVOT columnNumber;
```

As Access can not pivot more than two fields this query turns `tblPictures` into a table three fields, consisting of -

A group number based on the position of the record from `tblPictures` in a list that is sorted into ascending order of the values in `fldDescription`.  Each group is `40` `tblPictures` record in size, except the final group, which has how many records are left at that stage.

Each value from each relevant field from each record from `tblPictures`.

A field containing the name of the field that the value from `tblPictures` will be placed in once the `PIVOT` has been performed.

The applicable values of each record from `fldPictures` are placed within a group of controls on the form.  Each group consists of -

A text box called `txtID01` (or whatever number corresponds to the position on the page) that stores the value of `fldID`.  This control is for the program's reference purposes and does not need to be made available to the user.  As such it's `Visible` property is always set to `False`.
An image control called `imgPicture01` (or whatever number corresponds to the position on the page) that is used to display the image referred to by `fldPicture`.
A text box called `txtDescription01` (or whatever number corresponds to the position on the page) that displays the value of `fldDescription`.  This control is for display purposes, but does not need to be navigated to by the user.  As the control will be covered by a transparent command button, thus preventing it be clicked, it only needs to have its `Tab Stop` property set to `No`.

Each group is covered by a command button that has no `Caption` and has its `Back Style` property set to `Transparent`.  This is the button that will enable the user to choose the record regardless of whether or not they click on the `Picture`, `Description` or the "white-space" immediately surrounding them.

Each group's command button's `On Click` event has the following VBA code associated with it...

```
Private Sub cmd01_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDetails", , , "fldID = " & txtID01
End Sub
```

The above code opens the form `frmDetails`, which displays the details of the selected record, including the field `fldSynopsis`.

Each group's command button's `Got Focus` event has the following code associated with it...

```
Private Sub cmd01_GotFocus()
    Me.cmd01.BorderStyle = 1
End Sub
```

This code will change the `Border Style` property for the command button from `0` (`Transparent`) to `1` (`Solid`), causing the group of controls to be surrounded with a border highlighting their selection.

Each group's command button's `Lost Focus` event has the following code associated with it...

```
Private Sub cmd01_LostFocus()
    Me.cmd01.BorderStyle = 0
End Sub
```

This code will change the `Border Style` property for the command button from `1` (`Solid`) to `0` (`Transparent`), causing the border highlighting the group's selection to be removed when it ceases to be the current selection.

Across the top of the page are 28 buttons, one for each letter of the alphabet, one with the digit `9` and one with the character `*`.

When each of the letter buttons are clicked the following code is executed...

```
Private Sub cmdRefineToA_Click()
    RefineToLetter ("A")
End Sub
```

The summoned procedure `RefineToLetter()` follows...

```
Private Sub RefineToLetter(parameterLetter As String)
    Me.RecordSource = GetRefineToLetterString(parameterLetter)
    recordCount = DCount("*", "tblPictures", "LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = 'A'")

    SetNavigationControls
    ShowHideControls
End Sub
```

This procedure starts by getting a copy of the SQL statement that is the same as the one initially used to set the form's `RecordSource` property, but with each reference to `tblPictures` replaced with the following code...

```
SELECT fldID,
       fldDescription,
       fldPicture
FROM tblPictures
WHERE LEFT( fldDescription, 1 ) = 'A'
```

Unfortunately, Access does not like trying to `PIVOT` the results of parametrised queries, so the above statement needs to be constructed in VBA, then applied.  Also, please note that you can spread a statement out across multiple lines by turning each line into a string ending with `" & _`, but there is a limit to the amount of lines you can concatenate across in this way.

Once the form's `RecordSource` property has been set to the above query, the form will be refilled with all those records whose `fldDescription` value starts with that letter.

`RefineToLetter()` then recalculates the global variable `recordCount` (which holds the number of record from `tblPictures` meeting the current search criteria, then calls the procedures `SetNavigationControls` and `ShowHideControls`, which enable / disable the navigation buttons depending on the value of `recordCount` and hide / show the command buttons and `Description` controls corresponding to each record from `tblPictures` depending on whether or not they have a record to show.  By hiding the command buttons when they have no corresponding record we can prevent the user from attempting to choose a nonexistent record (thus avoiding any errors this could generate) and we also prevent the user from being able to tab to the control.  By hiding the `Description` control we hide the error message it displays when there is no value to poulate it with.

`SetNavigationControls` and `ShowHideControls` are also called when the page loads / changes by adding calls to the form's `ON Current` event.

The `9` button uses a variation on the above query that returns every record that starts with a digit.

The `*` button resets the `RecordSource` property to the query used to initially populate the form.

At the top and the bottom of the form are a pair of buttons that can be used to navigate between pages.  The back buttons use the following code to move back `1` page...

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
```

The forward buttons use the following code to move forward `1` page...

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord
```

Please note that when `DoCmd.GoToRecord` encounters no parameters it defaults to going to the next record in the form's record-set.

I hope to have a copy of what I have done so far up shortly.

Comment: Looking forward to trying ur idea out sounds very similar to the cross tab version I have except Im only using 1 form its slow because i have 4000 images to process and intend on at least 8000 before Im finished it allows a form popup to be selected from any image but sorting is a real problem as the cross tab doesnt have many fields to play with...I used thumbnails in the cut down version of my database 2 mb if there is anyway to upload it here ?

Comment: Have you considered breaking your output up into pages of, say, 100 images each?

Comment: Here is a link to my cross tab one and another I found that uses web sub form of which I know nothing about of editing etc: just extract to c:\Demo as to breaking up to pages,  the scrolling of the images doesn't seem to be an issue as it only takes about a sec to update next line even if u drag to the bottom of 4000 images it takes a sec or 2 to catch up, the problem is the sorting, in order to sort by genre and then by year, I have to do it before the cross tab is generated and the temp table made for every different type of sort.[link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuXDlimXyYZNhCluRN7_hQWufEfz)

Comment: May be there is a way to attach the sort fields I need to the end of the image path string then retrieve them from the cross tab table ?

Comment: I have updated my explanation and hope to be posting a link to my database soon.  Please feel free to reply with any questions or comments that you might have.

Comment: Thanks again for all ur help so far u have excelled. I would of thought Msaccess would have allowed for these situations by now. I have combined 6 pivot tables so far to give me 6 fields I can use on the form and the rest from the popup and that takes about a 90 seconds to generate the Temp Table then its pretty normal after that but no Ideas on the sorting yet I will Post My updated one again soon so u can laugh.

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem for ur sorting technique but the image files are named as such by the script that retrieves them eg: 90-A-Rage-in-Harlem--1991-.jpg,476-Borderline--1980-.jpg, but the preceding numbers do match the MovieId which matches the title, if that makes sense.

Comment: Tell me more about this script.  Also, tell me more about the structure of the table that you are using - is it the same as mine or something different?  Once I know how you are getting and storing your data I will be able to offer suggestions on how you can implement different sorting algorithms.

Comment: The Tables are from the software that I use to get all the information from the internet,[Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuXDlimXyYZNhCqBC-Veo_XZqFtb) its stored on my onedrive. In the Database are tables and nothing else,They must use vb for all the rest, I link only to the movies one and maybe Actors down the road.I dont alter the movies table at all,just use the columns I need So far Ive got it down to 2 min loading from 4min ,using 10 cross tabs to make 1 table I was wondering if vb querys would be faster and havent tried sorting, will post what Ive Got soon i a day or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem where I wanted to display 15 images per page of a form. I set up a grid of unbound boxes on the form called 'imgPoster1', 'imgPoster2' etc. With manual next page and previous page buttons with Page 1 of 10 between them (as controls txtPageNumber and txtOfPages)

This code then put 15 records per page in a grid of images with the poster name beneath each image.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPosters"

    ShowPosters strSQL, 1
    Me.txtPageNumber.Value = 1
    Me.txtOfPages.Value = Round(0.4 + DCount("PosterID", "tblPosters") / 15) 'adding 0.4 just rounds up

End Sub

Sub ShowPosters(strSQL As String, intStartRecordNumber As Integer)
    Dim intControlNumber As Integer
    Dim intRecordNumber As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    'On Error Resume Next 'for when poster image doesn't exist

    intControlNumber = 1
    intRecordNumber = 1

    Do While Not rs.EOF
      If intRecordNumber >= intStartRecordNumber And intRecordNumber < intStartRecordNumber + 15 Then
         If Len(rs.Fields("PosterCode")) > 0 Then
             Me.Controls("imgPoster" & intControlNumber).Picture = CurrentProject.Path & "\Attachments\" & rs.Fields("PosterCode") & ".jpg"
             Me.Controls("txtPosterCode" & intControlNumber).Value = rs.Fields("PosterCode") & " - " & rs.Fields("PosterGroup")
         End If

        Me.Controls("txtPosterName" & intControlNumber).Value = rs.Fields("PosterName")

        intControlNumber = intControlNumber + 1
     End If

        rs.MoveNext

        intRecordNumber = intRecordNumber + 1

   Loop

   'make any remaining controls blank

    Do While intControlNumber <= 15
         Me.Controls("imgPoster" & intControlNumber).Picture = ""
         Me.Controls("txtPosterCode" & intControlNumber).Value = ""
         Me.Controls("txtPosterName" & intControlNumber).Value = ""

        intControlNumber = intControlNumber + 1
    Loop
rs.Close
On Error GoTo 0
Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNextPage_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPosters"

    If CInt(Me.txtPageNumber.Value) < CInt(Me.txtOfPages.Value) Then
       Me.txtPageNumber.Value = Me.txtPageNumber.Value + 1
       ShowPosters strSQL, 1 + ((Me.txtPageNumber.Value - 1) * 15)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdPreviousPage_Click()

    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblPosters"


    If CInt(Me.txtPageNumber.Value) > 1 Then
        Me.txtPageNumber.Value = Me.txtPageNumber.Value - 1

        ShowPosters strSQL, 1 + ((Me.txtPageNumber.Value - 1) * 15)
    End If
End Sub
```